# Why can not I set image?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiimageview

Why can not I set image?

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITalbeViewDataSource{
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.setCell()
    return cell
  }
}


class CustomTableViewCell:UITableViewCell{
  @IBOutlet weak var artworkImage:UIImageView!

  func setCell(){
    let urlStr = "http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music20/v4/d4/6c/af/d46caf98-ff6c-1707-135d-58d6ed9ea6a2/source/500x500bb.jpg"
    let url = URL(strings: urlStr)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)

    if let imageData = data {
      self.artworkImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
  }
}
```

I want to display the image of the URL destination in TableView but the image is not displayed.

[image]

this image is log.

Comment: Do you call the function" setCell"?

Comment: sorry. I will add it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setCell()` should be like this

```
func setCell(){
    let urlStr = "http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music20/v4/d4/6c/af/d46caf98-ff6c-1707-135d-58d6ed9ea6a2/source/500x500bb.jpg"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    artworkImage.image = UIImage(named: "ic_placeholder")

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let imageData = data {
                self.artworkImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Image should be downloaded on background thread otherwise UI will be blocked. After downloading images you need to make changes in Main Thread.

Also better have a placeholder image.

Comment: Additional : Its better to cache the images.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set image in background thread, because of that you receive this logs. You need to use main thread while displaying image on imageView like:

```
if let imageData = data {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.artworkImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    })  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Lib for images particularly for ImageView on cell :-

https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift

let URLString = self.items[indexPath.row]

let URL = NSURL(string:URLString)!

cell.imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(URL)

Answer (score -1):

cell:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var artworkImage:UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
func setCell(){
    let urlStr = "http://is3.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music20/v4/d4/6c/af/d46caf98-ff6c-1707-135d-58d6ed9ea6a2/source/500x500bb.jpg"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let imageData = data {
            self.artworkImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        }        }

}
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Also do not forget. Set up `App Transport Security Settings`.
good luck

Comment: Image is already download on MAIN Thread. There is no need for call main thread again.